# Problem connecting via cable or wifi after update to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking, 20.04, ethernet, settings, wired

I have a Dell machine with dual partition between Linux and Windows.

During the times using Ubuntu, I have follow the system notice instruction to upgrade from Ubuntu 19.04 to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. After the packages were updated, and the system rebooted, I caould not get the cable Ethernet to work not any of the Wi-Fi networks previously available.

That problem only happens when log in Ubuntu, not happening when using the Windows! On Windows it is still working well on Ethernet cable and on wifi networks.

Can someone help or guide me to discovery what could be the issue and how to resolve it to get connection on Ubuntu again? I can provide terminal information to help.

I may also downgrade if that is available to fix this problem. Can anyone help or guide in any way? I have little experience with Linux and am still learning how to diagnose troubles within the system.

Thanks in advance for anyone who can help and I hope to get replies soon!

Laroc

Comment: I have a similar problem after update, on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Please type `lspci` in a terminal and edit your post to include the results.

Comment: @Raffles, I seem to have found my problem. It's very strange, but for some reason my router port died directly after rebooting after an update. This made me suspect the update. I'll leave my comment as typing lspci might help people find similar issues